# How to get exploded graph from clang analyzer

Tags: clang

I am trying to get exploded graph from one of the debug checkers called 
`debug.ViewExplodedGraph`.

So I run command

`clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=debug.ViewExplodedGraph someprogram.c`

It run successfully, but graph file no where to be found .
Where can we see the generated file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should  build the clang yourself. Then use the debug mode 'clang', call the command. The system clang is in release mode.

I use the system clang, it outputs nothing. But I use the clang that I build, it output something.

➜  bin ./clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=debug.ViewExplodedGraph ~/Desktop/clang_test/test.c
Writing '/var/folders/_6/5wkxc9p92t94vdh0kyq2qyh40000gn/T/ExprEngine-9e6797.dot'...  done.
Trying 'open' program... Remember to erase graph file: /var/folders/_6/5wkxc9p92t94vdh0kyq2qyh40000gn/T/ExprEngine-9e6797.dot
Warning: viewing graph requires assertions

➜  bin clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=debug.ViewExplodedGraph ~/Desktop/clang_test/test.c
Warning: viewing graph requires assertions

cd to T folder

➜  T dot -Tsvg ExprEngine-9e6797.dot -o ~/Desktop/test.svg

then use chrome open test.svg